# Problem installing mariadb

Tags: centos, package-management, yum, mysql, mariadb

I want install mariadb but i get this error

```
[root@wslb_206]# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)


[root@wslb_206]# yum install mariadb-server mariadb

--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 1:mariadb-server-5.5.56-2.el7.x86_64 (local)
           Requires: mariadb-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.5.56-2.el7
           Installed: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               mariadb-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.5.52-1.el7
Error: Package: 1:mariadb-5.5.56-2.el7.x86_64 (local)
           Requires: mariadb-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.5.56-2.el7
           Installed: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               mariadb-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.5.52-1.el7
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

how can i update `mariadb-libs-5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64` to `mariadb-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.5.56-2.el7` ?

thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`mariadb` is part of the base repo in CentOS 7 and should already be installed.  The incompatibilities are probably due to additional repos (e.g. IUS, EPEL) you configured.

Disable the third-party repos in `/etc/yum.repos.d/` by moving somewhere else all files that are not `CentOS-*.repo`, then try:

```
yum clean all
yum remove mariadb-libs
yum install mariadb-server
```

Answer (score 1):

If you've install MySQL 8 from MySQL community server and now you want to install `mariadb` instead, do the following:

1. do the `yum history` list to see all `yum` history:

   ```
   sudo yum --setopt=history_list_view=commands history list all
   ```
2. get the id from the line that you installed MySQL community server
3. do the following command to undo `mariadb` libs

   ```
   sudo yum history undo ID
   ```
4. now you should be able to install `mariadb` using the command:

   ```
    sudo yum install mariadb mariadb-server
   ```